# M3 Java: How to check that a class implements a function from an interface

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to write an analysis that checks that a class implements `Comparable.compareTo` |java+method:///java/lang/Comparable/compareTo(T)|.

I tried playing with M3.methodOverrides, and in some cases it works. But with the code below, methodOverrides does not contain compareTo at all.

```java
//Geometric.java
public interface Geometric extends Comparable<Geometric> {
    public double area();
}
```

```java
//Circle.java
public class Circle implements Geometric {

    private double r;
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Geometric o) {
        return (int) (area() - o.area());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle...";
    }

}
```

When loading these files using `createM3FromDirectory`, M3.methodOverrides contains only a single entry:

```
<|java+method:///Circle/area()|,|java+method:///Geometric/area()|>
```

Is there a way to take some transitive closures of some relations in M3 to conclude that
`|java+method:///Circle/compareTo(Geometric)|` overrides `|java+method:///java/lang/Comparable/compareTo(T)|`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe my eyes. I just tried it again, and now it works.

```
//Main.rsc
module Main

import IO;
import lang::java::m3::Core;

void main(list[str] args)
{
    loc projectDir = |file:///| + args[0];
    M3 model = createM3FromDirectory(projectDir);

    for( ov <- model.methodOverrides ) { println(ov); }
}
```

Inside eclipse rascal console:

```
rascal>main(["/home/mkl/radboud/src/java-feedback/java-feedback-rascal/test-data/assignment03-override-not-detected"]);
Reloading module Main
<|java+method:///Circle/toString()|,|java+method:///java/lang/Object/toString()|>
<|java+method:///Circle/area()|,|java+method:///Geometric/area()|>
<|java+method:///Circle/compareTo(Geometric)|,|java+method:///java/lang/Comparable/compareTo(T)|>
```

There it is: Circle actually implements Comparable.compareTo.
`<|java+method:///Circle/compareTo(Geometric)|,|java+method:///java/lang/Comparable/compareTo(T)|>`

I think the problem was that I'm using two different versions of rascal. Rascal shell, which seems to be an older version, gives different results.

Using rascal-shell:

```
$ java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar ~/tmp/rascal-shell-stable.jar Main.rsc /home/mkl/radboud/src/java-feedback/java-feedback-rascal/test-data/assignment03-override-not-detected
Version: unknown
<|java+method:///Circle/area()|,|java+method:///Geometric/area()|>
```

I think I was only running rascal-shell. When running from inside eclipse, it gives the correct results.

As far as I'm concerned it works as expected.

P.S. I understand that M3 only records immediate facts, and that I have to calculate transitive closures myself when needed.

Comment: hi Marcus, did you install the unstable version of rascal in eclipse? since the stable jar is 2y behind at least. try the unstable version of the jar.

Comment: Yes, I installed the unstable version, and it works fine. I'm using the unstable versions of both eclipse and shell rascal now.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, M3 only stores method overrides related to the immediate superclass and interfaces. If the transitive interfaces and super types are declared within your project, you can use the transitive closure of the `implements` and `extends` relation, and then crosscheck results against the `declarations` and `containment` relations. However, you need to be aware that in the case of external dependencies (e.g. `Comparable<T>`) you won't have all the needed information in your M3. Thus, this is not a general workaround to solve all cases. If you still want to check method overrides for the project entities, consider the following steps (this is just one possible solution):

1. Compute transitive closure of the `implements` relation.
2. Compute transitive closure of the `extends` relation.
3. Suscribe to both relations based on the type you are checking and aggregate both sets (i.e. `transImpl[|java+class://main/MyClass|] + transExt[|java+class://main/MyClass|]`).
4. Consider the methods in the `containment` relation related to the `MyClass` type and its transitive parent types.
5. Compare the signatures of the `MyClass` methods against transitive parent types methods (be aware of the visibility of each method; only `protected` and `public` methods should be consider).

In any case we have opened a new [issue](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1252) in the Rascal repository to further analyze your inquiry. Thanks for reporting it.